# Logistic Regression:Panel Data(already tried glmer not working)

Tags: r, panel, logistic-regression, glm

I am trying to solve a problem of logistic regression which needs me to predict if a user will click on a email campaign. The problem that I am facing is that multiple campaigns are sent to a single user so I have panel data and I need to predict the click probability of a user for a particular campaign.
How can I deal with this sort of data for logistic regression?

```
user_id      campaign_type          send_date
1             newsletter             1-jan-17
2             upcomingevents         2-jan-17
1             informational email    3-jan17
2             newsletter             4-jan-17
```

Comment: I don't think your use of the term "panel data" actually fits the usual usage. Panel data as the term is usually deployed refers to repeated measurements on the same variables at equal time intervals. (Think GDP measured as a function of labor and investment variables over multiple quarters.) You have a multinomial outcome if you are predicting whether a user is going to pick a particular outcome.  Logistic regression is used for binomial outcomes. I think you need to seek statistical advice to get your problem lined up with your choice of analysis methods. (Not ready for coding question.)

Comment: I think the data is fitting the panel definition as we have mutiple rows for the same user and we are trying to predict if he clicks on that email or not which would have values-0 or 1(which is binomial),so logistic regression would be the correct choice but I am stuck with the mutliple rows for the same user as he can get similar type of email campaign on different dates.How to handle that type of data structure?I guess that should be panel data only as we have repeated user_id.